# Register form connected to database myphpadmin

Tags: php

I have this register form but I have an error in it.
Under the register form it appears this code:

```
document.write = 'Account created';";{ else { echo 'Error :('; } } ?>
```

and this is the entire code from it:

```
if ($db=query("INSERT INTO prof
    (username,email,fname,lname,country,password)
    VALUES ('$username','$email','$fname','$lname','$country','$password')"))
    print "<script>document.write = ('Account created');</script>";

{

     else {
        echo 'Error :(';
    }
  }
 ?>
```

how can I solve the issue?

Comment: please edit your question to format better the code. I think there are some syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors and your code is vulnerable to Sql Injections.

Using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), your code should be something like that:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO prof (username, email, fname, lname, country, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$insert = $stmt->execute([$username, $email, $fname, $lname, $country, $password]);

if ($insert) {
    print "<script>document.write = ('Account created');</script>";
} else {
    echo 'Error :(';
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work,Isn't my code I just found it free,everything else look fine just last "if" doesnt work properly can you help me please?

Comment: write more other than "doesn't work". What you mean?

Comment: is just showing me that code i wrote above,the register form looks good,maybe you wanna see it with teamviewer?i have more php files

Comment: you are missing something. If your page shows the code I wrote it means PHP interpreter is not running properly. So the problem is everywhere else